# how i can make textbox accept number followed by + sign or - sign

Tags: c#, regex

I want the prevent use from enter any text except text start with number and end 
with + sign or - sign ?

Comment: Try this one: `^[0-9]+[+-]$` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7sDmwP/1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^\d.*[+-]$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPIrbo/5)

Sample Source: ( [run here](https://ideone.com/tZTSsn) )

```
    string pattern = @"^\d.*[+-]$";
    string input = @"1adfasdf-";

    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    Match match = regex.Match(input);
    if (match.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    else
         Console.WriteLine("clear the input field and show an error message if you want");
```

Comment: But this will also match strings like `12waew+`. Not sure if the OP wants it this way

Comment: op didn't mention what will be there in between the first digit and the last sign therefore it is regarded as wildcard

Answer (score 0):

You can set the regex in the `pattern` attribute on the input, and set the error message on the `title` attribute. The regex for your case should be `[0-9].*[+-]`.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" title="The text must start with a number and end with a + or -" pattern="[0-9].*[+-]" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```